# using href after picking date from calendar

Tags: html, asp.net, hyperlink, href

On my asp.net site the calendar control is at the bottom of the page. When the user picks a date the `postback` is fired, the site reloads and the user has to scroll down again.

Is it possible to use a `href` so after the user picks the date the `postback` link to the `href`?

When I use `Response.Redirect("MySite.aspx#Datepicker");` when `calendar_SelectionChanged` the browser jumps to the `href` but the input reset. Thanks

Comment: Try this in `document.ready`. `$('html, body').scrollTop( $(document).height() );`

Comment: Thanks but I need a solution only for the calendar control, it should only scroll down when a date is picked

Comment: so you can put a check if date was selected than apply this code.

Answer (score 0):

Found this simple solution:

`calendar_SelectionChanged`:

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#Datepicker';", true);`